# Learn Ruby Hard Way ex. 48

Tags: ruby

I'm endeavoring to learn Ruby, and have made it through most of Learn Ruby the Hard Way by Zed Shaw, but this latest exercise has me completely stumped. It is a reverse exercise of sorts, getting you to create a class Lexicon that can get tested by the code provided.

You're supposed to create Lexicon so that it can go through user input and get various bits of data from it. So far all I have for testing direction input, for example is:

```
class Lexicon

Pair = Struct.new(:qualifier, :value)
userinput = gets.chomp()
userwords = userinput.split()

for i in userwords
    if userwords[i].include?("north", "south", "east", "west")
        directions = Pair.new("direction", userwords[i])
    else
        i++
    end
end     
end
```

The corresponding testing code is:

```
require 'test/unit'
require_relative "../lib/lexicon"

class LexiconTests < Test::Unit::TestCase

Pair = Lexicon::Pair
@@lexicon = Lexicon.new()

def test_directions()
assert_equal([Pair.new(:direction, 'north')], @@lexicon.scan("north"))
result = @@lexicon.scan("north south east")
assert_equal(result, [Pair.new(:direction, 'north'),
             Pair.new(:direction, 'south'),
             Pair.new(:direction, 'east')])
end
```

Thank you all in advance for the help. I know I'm probably way off, but am trying to go through the home stretch of learning Ruby the Hard Way!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Basically, the testing code I put at the bottom, needs to test a class Lexicon that you're supposed to create. I made an attempt at creating the class, and getting user input on direction, but am pretty sure I'm not understanding the exercise. The original can be found at http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex48.html#scanning-input

Comment: "we're supposed"? Really? How will you learn from this?

Comment: When I said "you're", I didn't mean you the people answering my question, I meant people who are going through the exercise, which is me. I did make an attempt at going through it and creating the class, which is above in my original post, but I am pretty sure it is off and not working correctly with the test code.

Comment: Anyway, so you're basically asking us to do the exercise. As I'm saying, there's little benefit in it for you. You're supposed to do it to learn. Make mistakes, try and learn. There are hints on that page: "Concentrate on making one test working at a time and keep it simple". I suggest you give it another try. At least, you'll be able to ask questions that are more concrete.

Comment: Looking at the exercise, it seems to me that your `Lexicon` class should define a method called `scan` that takes a string as input and returns an array of Pairs.  That should be your starting place (and I don't see it in your code above).  Note that the Lexicon class should not try to get user input itself, that will be passed in to the `scan` method.

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but since you are learning... doesn't that code teach you any traditional Ruby code style? As far as I know, Zed Shaw is mainly a Python programmer. Coincidentally, this looks a lot like Python code to me. Actually, it really seems he just adapted the entire exercise from the Python version and didn't bother with code conventions.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira: that's why it's called "the hard way". Because it makes reading proper ruby code harder. :)

Comment: Seeing `i++` in there means this cannot be fully Ruby where it would be `i += ` since there is no `++` operator.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira: Actually, Zed Shaw is one of the most prolific Ruby programmers there is. And the book definitely *does* teach good Ruby style. I'm not sure why the OP violates pretty much every single Ruby Coding Standard, but he surely didn't get that from Zed.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your for loop in a scan method because that's what the test case is expecting.
The scan method also needs to return a list of 'Pairs'.

Try something like this.

```
def scan(userwords)
  sentence = Array.new
  userwords.each { |word|
    if word.include?("north", "south", "east", "west")
      sentence.push(Pair.new(:direction, word))
  }
  sentence
end
```

That should help get you started in the right direction.